# Styling layer popup within arcgis.com

Tags: arcgis-online

While sophisticated styling of popups (infowindows when clicking on a point) are probably better in css, are there any options for styling infowindows within an arcgis.com webmap?

I really just want a less-technical user to be able to style the background, header color, and basic layout.